# replacing border of text input with image

Tags: html, css

i have a image of straight line which i would like to replace bottom border of input text box.

```
 div{
   border-image:url("image.png");
 }
```

is this right approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better create an Image like box and use it as background image.

If you want to use `border-image` refer this http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Comment: @peter: i've several input text box in a single page, it wouldn't be a wise choice to use background image, i just need the straight line image to be over-lapped with bottom border which is ofcourse hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a width for the border, complete parameters for the image. You should change this parameters depending on the image.

```
border-width:25px 30px 10px 20px;
border-image:url("image.png") 25 30 10 20 repeat;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563460/replacing-border-of-text-input-with-image/12563560#12563560